# Print contents of JSON Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an object in which I used JSON Stringify with to view its contents like so:

```
var testing = JSON.stringify($scope.test, null, 4);
```

And the object looks like this when i do `console.log(testing)`:

```
{
"_id": "53e866a8a595b7041f9510c9",
"start": "2014-08-04T07:00:00.000Z",
"end": "2014-08-16T07:00:00.000Z",
"location": "Australia",
"name": "Joe's Surprise",
"__v": 1,
"array": [
    {
        "_id": "53ddc8c98ae4813c0420e189",
        "provider": "local",
        "name": "Test User",
        "username": "testUser",
        "email": "test@test.com",
        "hashedPassword": "e5ri7OVhzNQMZpSqxnB3p2FyrpxskFE3yM8jHn5hfzZZvdd57YhhJrjFWJqBQhhyZz6y8UG68mr+rQ95admtfw==",
        "salt": "PVEFtMfyJ/7TX9Do0cYMdQ==",
        "__v": 2,
        "attending": [
            "53e866a8a595b7041f9510c9"
        ],
        "role": "user"
    },
]
```

}

however, I want to print out the username attribute within the `array` attribute of variable testing but I am unable to do so. I've tried doing a for loop like so:

```
for(var i = 0; i < testing.array.length; i++){
    console.log(testing.array[i].username);
}
```

But the .length attribute is considered `undefined`. I've also tried simply doing `console.log(testing._id)` to see if that works but this returns `undefined`. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: uhm, is `testing` still a string?

Comment: you misunderstood JSON.parse and JSON.stringify, no ?

Comment: what about for each? http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 var testing = JSON.stringify($scope.test, null, 4);
```

is converting $scope.test into a string (presumably so you can view in a human readible format).  A string contains no arrays or properties.  You want it in its original form, not in a string.

you probably want:

```
 for(var i = 0; i < $scope.test.array.length; i++){
     console.log($scope.test.array[i].username);
 }
```